# Facing issue in converting geo_ip to geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, kibana-7

how to extract or convert geoip to geopoint:

I do get geo info, but geo_point data type is missing. and i am not getting geo.location as geo_point, what else is needed in logstash to be done ?

So that i can get geo_point (longitude ,latitude) to visualize on maps, please guide

Comment: You should share your Logstash configuration

Comment: geoip{
        source => "IP"

        fields => ["longitude","latitude"]
        target => "client.geo.location"




    }

Comment: Ok, and what do you get? What is stored in your ES index? What is the mapping of that index? please update your question with as much info as possible.

Comment: {
  "longitude": 78.4564,
  "latitude": 17.3841
}. This is what i get in kibana, Json looks like "client.geo.location": {
      "longitude": 78.4564,
      "latitude": 17.3841
    },

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment  and update your question with all the details.